# Display list of most recent grandchild (third tier) pages

Tags: query

I currently have a piece of code I'm using to display a list of the three most recent 'special' custom post type posts which will display an image, title and content of these posts.

I'm trying to modify my code to show only third tier posts (get rid of parent and child pages and show only grandchildren).

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<?php
                $query_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'special',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
                $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
                while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            ?>
```

As mentioned, this works perfectly to show the most recent posts, but I have been unable to get this to show only third tier.

For example, I've tried this:

```
'child_of' =>'.$post->ID.'
```

to no avail.

I've also tried implementing suggestions from a number of threads:

[Best Practice For Querying Grandchildren?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84810/best-practice-for-querying-grandchildren)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Rob

EDIT -

I've made some headway.
I've managed to remove top tier posts from displaying however second tier items still remain. My code is as follows:

In functions.php

```
 function wpse29897_no_parents( $where, $query )
 {
     if( isset( $query->query_vars['special'] ) && 'special' ==        $query->query_vars['post_type'] )
{
    if( '' != $where )
    {
        $where .= ' AND post_parent !=  0';
    }
    else
    {
        $where .= ' post_parent != 0';
    }
}
return $where;
 }
```

My query in the template:

```
 <?php
            add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse29897_no_parents', 10, 2 );
                $query_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'special',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
                $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
                while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            ?>
```

Comment: Is this for grandchildren of a particular post, or any 3rd-level `special`?

Comment: Any 3-rd level special custom post type

Comment: This would be easy if WP_Query or get_pages supported 'depth' like wp_list_pages does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only (easy) way this can be done is to query all `special`, calculate their depth, and then build a new stack of 3-level deep:

```
$grandkids = array();
$specials  = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
    )
);

foreach ( $specials as $special ) {
    if ( count( get_post_ancestors( $special ) ) === 2 ) {
        $grandkids[] = $special;

        if ( count( $grandkids ) === 3 )
            break;
    }
}

foreach ( $grandkids as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Actually there is an issue with this. I have this code in a sidebar in my custom post types 'singles' template. If I visit a post, the post is included up the top in the sidebar. Also 'posts_per_page' is set to 12 but only showing 3.

I did however manage to find a solution to my problem. All my third level posts share a unique custom field that is not being used by a top or second level post. Therefore, I've added 'meta_key' => 'key-name' to my args.

Comment: Nice one. Although worth mentioning, you need `posts_per_page => -1` initially to get *all* posts, in order to calculate which ones are three levels deep. Any limits should be placed in the subsequent `foreach` loop.